# cannot run exp start on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ubuntu-16.04, expo

When I run exp start on Ubuntu I get the following:

Usage : exp [-h] [-v level] [-o outfile] [infile]

-h     this help
  -v     verbose mode (level is 1:2:3:4)
  -o     define the output file (stdout by default)
  infile define the input file (stdin by default)

WHat do I else need to install exceptI installed exp globaly using npm command!

Comment: How exactly are you starting the application?

Comment: initally npm install , then exp start!

Comment: @Timo is there any specific way of running exp start in ubuntu

Comment: I don't think this is the exp for reactJS you might be thinking of. Please do: `npm install -g exp`, not apt-get or anything like that.